# Force acting on a pole which is fixed with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A uniform pole of weight 50kg is balanced in the vertical position. The length of the whole pole is 6m.the pole is fixed at point C on the ground.A force 500N is applied at B which is 2m from C. If the coefficient of kinetic friction between pole and the surface is 0.3. The initial acceleration of point A is (take g=10).

Comment: What is your question?